# postfix/cleanup bad trivial-rewrite

Tags: postfix

I use munin, the monitoring program, to alert me by email when something goes wrong on my server.
It sends emails as `munin`.

Normally, when an email like this is to be delivered on the Internet, when `postfix/cleanup` is called, it asks `trivial-rewrite` to do a [rewrite](http://www.postfix.org/trivial-rewrite.8.html), which should append `realdomain.tld` to incomplete sender address.

It seams it does not, because my Postfix SMTP client then tries to send the email containing the `From: munin@thehostname` header, which Google doesn't really like:

```
Jul 22 10:00:15 thehostname postfix/pickup[3167]: 979BD1E447E: uid=110 from=<munin@thehostname>
Jul 22 10:00:15 thehostname postfix/cleanup[9609]: 979BD1E447E: message-id=<20130722080015.979BD1E447E@realdomain.tld>
Jul 22 10:00:15 thehostname postfix/qmgr[3276]: 979BD1E447E: from=<munin@thehostname>, size=454, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 22 10:00:16 thehostname postfix/smtp[9611]: 979BD1E447E: to=<me@emailhandledbygoogle.com>, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[173.194.67.27]:25, delay=0.49, delays=0.07/0/0.12/0.3, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[173.194.67.27] said: 550-5.7.1 [9.8.7.6       1] Our system has detected an unusual rate of 550-5.7.1 unsolicited mail originating from your IP address. To protect our 550-5.7.1 users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has been blocked. 550-5.7.1 Please visit http://www.google.com/mail/help/bulk_mail.html to review 550 5.7.1 our Bulk Email Senders Guidelines. x12si10440172wia.27 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Jul 22 10:00:16 thehostname postfix/cleanup[9609]: 372F91E4483: message-id=<20130722080016.372F91E4483@realdomain.tld>
Jul 22 10:00:16 thehostname postfix/qmgr[3276]: 372F91E4483: from=<>, size=3167, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 22 10:00:16 thehostname postfix/bounce[9614]: 979BD1E447E: sender non-delivery notification: 372F91E4483
Jul 22 10:00:16 thehostname postfix/qmgr[3276]: 979BD1E447E: removed
Jul 22 10:00:16 thehostname postfix/local[9617]: 372F91E4483: to=<munin@thehostname>, relay=local, delay=0.13, delays=0.05/0.01/0/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Jul 22 10:00:16 thehostname postfix/qmgr[3276]: 372F91E4483: removed
```

I don't know why the **trivial-rewrite** doesn't work as expected for the `munin` user and why doesn't it get a proper sender address before the email is sent on the internet.

Other programs like `fail2ban` succeed to send emails and are rewrote to `fail2ban@realdomain.tld`...

Here is the interesting part of my configuration:

```
myhostname = realdomain.tld
mydomain = thehostname
mydestination = localhost.localdomain, localhost, $mydomain, $myhostname
myorigin = $myhostname
mynetworks =
relayhost =
```

I think there must be something I don't understand in the rewrite process!

**EDIT**

I found this on **[an article](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/cours/postfix/doc/rewrite.html)** talking about postfix addresses rewriting.

> Rewrite **user** to **user@$myorigin**
>
> This feature is controlled by the boolean **append_at_myorigin** parameter (default: yes). The purpose is to get consistent treatment
>   of user on every machine in $myorigin.

I haven't changed the **append_at_myorigin** parameter, which should be set "yes". $myorigin is set to realdomain.tld, but the rewriting goes wrong and choose $mydomain instead.

Comment: Are you using procmail?

Comment: Yes I use procmail, but I think this program is only called for local delivery (like for the bounce message which was sent to `munin@thehostname`). But for the email I'm talking about **qmgr** gave it to **smtp**, not to **local** process.

Comment: I just edited my post to add more information.

Answer (score 1):

From the first log line

```
Jul 22 10:00:15 thehostname postfix/pickup[3167]: 979BD1E447E: uid=110 from=<munin@thehostname>
```

we can conclude that munin daemon set sender as `munin@thehostname` not `munin` only (without domain part) as your assumption.

---

**As a proof**, I send email via sendmail CLI

```
$ mail someone@example.com
Subject: test
test
```

Above command will add queue in `queue_directory`/maildrop. Run postcat command to view the queue content

```
$ sudo postcat -q 5A1AD347819 
*** ENVELOPE RECORDS maildrop/5A1AD347819 ***
message_arrival_time: Thu Oct  9 23:02:43 2014
named_attribute: rewrite_context=local
sender_fullname: User
sender: myuser
recipient: someone@example.com
*** MESSAGE CONTENTS maildrop/5A1AD347819 ***
To: someone@example.com
Subject: test

test
*** HEADER EXTRACTED maildrop/5A1AD347819 ***
*** MESSAGE FILE END maildrop/5A1AD347819 ***
```

In this case the sender was only `myuser` without domain part. Here entry of maillog when sending.

```
Oct  9 23:05:11 web postfix/pickup[79682]: 9808834784D: uid=1010 from=<zagalo>
Oct  9 23:05:11 web postfix/cleanup[79684]: 9808834784D: message-id=<20141009160511.9808834784D@web.example.com>
Oct  9 23:05:11 web postfix/qmgr[79683]: 9808834784D: from=<zagalo@web.example.com>, size=318, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

---

So, trivial rewrite has nothing to do in your case. Your email has proper sender address, so it hadn't rewritten.

**Solution?**

- Tell munin to change the sender address (my quick googling didn't provide useful results).
- As alternative, set smtp_generic_maps to providing the rewrite for your munin.

  ```
  /etc/postfix/main.cf:
      smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic

  /etc/postfix/generic:
      munin@thehostname       munin@realdomain.tld
  ```